# Como ativar um item de navegação dinamicamente

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

cansei de sempre alterar a `navbar` de todas as minhas páginas, e resolvi criar um arquivo pra `navbar` e sempre dar um `include` nas páginas para ser mais fácil a adição/remoção de itens!

Só que, minha dúvida é se tem como fazer um sistema em `PHP` ou `JavaScript` que possa identificar a página para setar a classe `'active'` no `<li>` da `navbar` correspondente a página atual!

O código da NavBar é o seguinte:

```html
<div class="container">

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">

  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">

      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">

        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>

        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>

    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        <li class="active clash"><a href="/">Início</a></li>

        <li class="clash"><a href="/ferramentas/gerador-de-emblema">Gerador de Emblemas</a></li>

      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

      </ul>

    </div>

  </div>

</nav>

</div>
```

Por exemplo, estou na página `HOME`! Digamos que o `id` da `body` é `"1"`.
Um script poderia capturar esse `id` e atribuir a classe `active` para a `<li>` com a id `"1"`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma opção simples e eficaz é comparar o retorno da url com o valor do href em seu menu de navegação, aplicando a classe no elemento quando a condição fosse satisfeita.

**Solução em PHP**(comparando url com href)

```
<?php $paginaLink = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];?>
<li>
  <a href="/blog/"
  <?php 
    if($paginaLink == '/blog/index.php') {echo 'class="ativo"';}
  ?>>
  Blog</a>
</li>
```

Essa não é das minhas soluções preferidas porque acaba sujando um pouco o `HTML` do menu, mas é bem simples e eficaz.

**Solução em JQuery**(Comparando atributos)
Aproveitando sua linha de raciocínio, você também pode solucionar seu problema usando `JQuery` comparando por exemplo se o valor da propriedade `name` do `<body>` de sua página é igual ao valor da propriedade `name` de cada `<li>` do menu de navegação.

```
$("nav ul li").each(function() {
  var page_name = $("body").attr("name");
  var menu_name = $(this).attr("name");
  if(page_name == menu_name){
    $(this).addClass("active");
    return false;  
    // retornando false vc evita que o loop continue iterando,
    // supondo que seu menu não precise de 2 itens com classe ativa
  }
});
```

Comment: cara, não sei porque, mas descartei totalmente a opção .val() da minha mente por isso fiquei sem ideias kkkk, vou tentar essa com jquery!

Comment: verdade mano, o .val() não funciona com attr()! Removi os .val() e deu certo, funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: Eu nem testei, se tivesse testado, tinha notado isso, .val() removido!

Comment: Acho que JavaScript é a melhor opção, eu pensei em PHP para fazer algum tipo de classe ou sla, nunca mexi com classes!